# Pybind11 - Casting a list of abstract-inherited class elements

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have one pure abstract class and 2 inherited classes where each contains a method called `go` as follows:

```c++
// Pure abstract class
class Animal {
public:
    virtual std::string go() = 0;
};

// First inherited class
class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    std::string go() override { return "woof! "; }
};

// Second inherited class
class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    std::string go() override { return "meow! "; }
};
```

On the Python side, a list of instantiated objects (either Dog or Cat) is defined. On the C++ side, I'm trying to write a function `call_go`, which takes this Python list as an input, and calls the method `go` of each object of the list.

```python
import test

# defining a list of objects Cat or Dog
animals = []
animals.append(test.Cat())
animals.append(test.Dog())
animals.append(test.Cat())

# trying to call for each object of the given list the method "go"
test.call_go(animals)
```

As I do not know in advance the type of each element of the given list, I tried to write the function `call_go` where I cast the element as `Animal`:

```c++
void call_go(py::list animals) {
  for (py::handle animal : animals) {
    std::cout << py::cast<Animal>(animal).go() << " ";
  }
}
```

But, as `Animal` is a an abstract class, the compiler returns:

> error: invalid abstract return type ‘Animal’

However, if the list is fully defined within the c++ code, it compiles and runs perfectly fine:

```c++
void call_go_cpp() {
  std::list<Animal*> animals;

  animals.push_back(new Cat());
  animals.push_back(new Dog());
  animals.push_back(new Cat());

  for(Animal* animal: animals)
    std::cout << animal->go() << std::endl;
}
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem? I suppose it involves writing a custom cast.

The full C++ code is here:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

// Pure abstract class
class Animal {
public:
    virtual std::string go() = 0;
};

class PyAnimal : public Animal {
public:
    using Animal::Animal;
    std::string go() override { PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_PURE( std::string, Animal, go, ); }
};

// First inherited class
class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    std::string go() override { return "woof! "; }
};

class PyDog : public Dog {
public:
    using Dog::Dog;
    std::string go() override { PYBIND11_OVERRIDE(std::string, Dog, go, ); }
};

// Second inherited class
class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    std::string go() override { return "meow! "; }
};

class PyCat : public Cat {
public:
    using Cat::Cat;
    std::string go() override { PYBIND11_OVERRIDE(std::string, Cat, go, ); }
};

// calling the method "go" for each element of a list (instance of class Dog or Cat) created within the c++ code 
void call_go_cpp() {
  std::list<Animal*> animals;

  animals.push_back(new Cat());
  animals.push_back(new Dog());
  animals.push_back(new Cat());

  for(Animal* animal: animals)
    std::cout << animal->go() << std::endl;
}

// trying to call the method "go" for each element of a list (instance of class Dog or Cat) defined on the Python side
void call_go(py::list animals) {
  for (py::handle animal : animals) {
    std::cout << py::cast<Animal>(animal).go() << " ";
  }
}

// Pybind11 bindings
PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m) {
    py::class_<Animal, PyAnimal>(m, "Animal")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("go", &Animal::go);

    py::class_<Dog, Animal, PyDog>(m, "Dog")
        .def(py::init<>());

    py::class_<Cat, Animal, PyCat>(m, "Cat")
        .def(py::init<>());

    m.def("call_go_cpp", &call_go_cpp);
    m.def("call_go", &call_go);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to write `call_go` is

```
void call_go(py::list animals) {
  for (py::handle animal : animals) {
    // wrong 
    //std::cout << py::cast<Animal>(animal).go() << " ";
    // correct way
    std::cout << py::cast<Animal *>(animal)->go() << " ";
  }
}
```

Thanks to the pybind11 community at https://gitter.im/pybind/Lobby for the solution